# Why does closing someone's eyes not give them near-sightedness?

Tags: optics, vision, biology

When we close our eyes aren't we technically looking a really close up piece of skin? That is, our eyelids? If it's so close to our eyes why doesn't it give us bad vision? We know if screens or books or other objects constantly being close to us causes our vision to get worse, why doesn't the eyelid do the same thing? What's the difference?

Comment: I think the difference is that you aren't focusing on anything when you close your eyes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a biology question, not a physics question

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that's funny because someone there told me it was a physics question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/100519/why-does-closing-someones-eyes-not-give-them-near-sightedness?noredirect=1#comment181331_100519

Comment: @PSUChange  Oh, well,  guess nobody wants to dive into the details :-(  of the reasons.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft time to make it my dissertation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to answer your question you have to think about how the eye works. Light reflects off of an object and strikes the back of the eye to trigger the individual sensors that detect light. When you move your eyelid over your eye there is no light striking the light sensor in the back of your eye and the brain doesnt make any adjustments.

Comment: This is probably true, but I'd like to see some citations from the world of Biology or Human opthalmology

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes only when we try to focus on something that is really close to our eyes. We don't try to focus on our eyelid (may be we cannot), and hence its not a problem

Comment: You can if you shine a light in your face and try to look at floaters. Takes effort though and you need to notice the floaters to begin with and really focus because floaters are behind the lens so you can't truly focus on them, but you can try.